# Understand Output of diff -u

Tags: bash, unix, diff

I am trying to understand the output of "diff -u". I did

```
diff -u file_x file_y
```

I got the following output:

```
diff -u file_x file_y
--- file_x 2019-07-14 10:46:03.000000000 +0530
+++ file_y  2019-07-14 10:46:10.000000000 +0530

@@ -392,7 +392,7 @@
```

What does `@@ -392,7 +392,7 @@` mean? Does it mean that...

```
in file_x, 7 lines starting from line number 392 changed
```

Comment: Did you search at all? Wikipedia's explanation is literally my top Google hit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `diff -u` command you used means "unified diff", so the `-392,7` refers to the first file (the `-` aka `file_x`) starting from line 392 where 7 lines are shown and similarly `+392,7` refers to the second file (the `+` aka `file_y`) starting from line 392 where 7 lines are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jojo's correct and complete answer, I just wanted to point you to the official documentation:

While UNIX documentation was traditionally in manual pages (`man diff`), the GNU project prefers the "texinfo" documentation format, so the more extensive diff documention can be found in that format, which you can see with the `info diff` command. It is also available online on GNU's site, with the relevant part on the unified diff format (diff -u) at: https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unified-Format.html.